# I am getting this error: (#278) Reading advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission ads_read

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am using the Graph Explorer to check an information. The page is:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

I am getting this error:
 (#278) Reading advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission ads_read

where can I set the permission for ads_read?

thanks

Comment: Get Token -> Get User Access Token …?